# How do i write a text(.txt) file to a dataframe without using RDDs and print it on a console

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to write a .txt file to a dataframe and print it on console

I have tried it printing in the same manner as i was printing a .csv file to the console through dataframes

def txtreader():DataFrame={

```
val loadTxt=spark.read
            .format("txt")
  .option("header","true")
  .load("C:\\Users\\1591532\\Spark-Learning-Workspace\\Text Files\\abc.txt")

return loadTxt
```

I am getting an error "Failed to find data source: txt."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark 1.6 and higher, you can use the csv data source:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("file.txt")
```

For your case, You can also specify header option, delimeter etc e.g.:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ";").csv("file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code to read the text file.

```
scala> spark.read.text("sample.txt")
res34: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> res34.show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  abc|
+-----+
```